# How to update Kivy ActionGroup display when a widget is added to it?

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently trying to add, remove, and display the contents/widgets dynamically in an ActionGroup widget. When I try to add an ActionButton to an ActionGroup, the widget gets added to the ActionGroup. However when I click the ActionGroup (spinner mode) on program test run, the widget that I added was not shown. It only shows when I resize the App window, forcing it to refresh then allow the ActionButton that I added to be shown. How can I make that when I add an ActionButton it is shown immediately and not make me do some resizing on the App window just to make it appear.

I tried looking on how to refresh the ActionBar or the ActionView similar on how it refreshes when I try to resize the window. However the documentation does not show any methods on how to make it.

**python code**

```
class ThirstyWellRoot(BoxLayout):
     def create_graph(self, port):
        graph_controller = GraphController(port, name=port.port_name)
        action_button = ActionButton(text=port.port_name)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(graph_controller)
        self.action_group.add_widget(action_button)
```

**kv code**

```
<ThirstyWellRoot>:
    action_group: action_group
    screen_manager: screen_manager
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: tertiary_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
    ActionBar:
        height: 50
        ActionView:
            id: action_view
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                with_previous: False
                app_icon: 'assets/theme/logo.png'
                on_release: root.about()
            ActionGroup:
                id: action_group
                mode: 'spinner'
                text: 'PORTS'
            ActionGroup:
                text: 'DISPLAY'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'ADD'
                    on_release: root.add_connection()
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'OPEN'
                    on_release: root.open_graph()
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'REMOVE'
                    on_release: root.remove_graph()
            ActionGroup:
                text: 'COMMANDS'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'MONITOR'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'STOP'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'RESET'
```

The expected would be that as I add the ActionButton to the ActionGroup, the widget that I added should be visible immediately as I press the ActionGroup (spinner mode). However, it does not show immediately and it only shows when I resize the window, forcing it to overflow (ActionOverflow from ActionView) and show the ActionButton that I added.

As I add the button

[image: As I add the button]

After I added the button it does not show up as I press the ActionGroup

[image: After I add the button it does not show up as I press the ActionGroup]

It only shows up when I tried few minimize and maximize window commands

[image: It only shows up when I tried few minimize and maximize window commands]